# Ignore specific properties conditionally DTO

Tags: java, json, rest, api, swagger

I have a specific requirement, I have a single POJO like EmployeeDTO.java

with below Fields;

```
int employeeId;
String Name;
double salary;
String createdBy;
Date createdTimestamp;
String updatedBy;
Date updatedTimestamp;
```

Now my reqirement is while I will get a Create API request as a JOSN I shouldn't get any fields like employeeId, createdBy, createdTimestamp, updatedBy, updatedTimestamp.

But in a GET API response, I should send all these fields.

I can't use jsonIgnore here as for a field like employeeId I am not expcting it in the request, but I want to send it in the response.

In a PATCH/PUT api call I am expecting employeeId from UI in the request but not below 4 fields createdBy, createdTimestamp, updatedBy, updatedTimestamp.

So a simple solutions can be I can create separate DTOs, like EmployeeDTO, EmployeeCreateRequestDTO, EmployeeUpdateRequestDTO. But it will leads to duplication of codes.

Is there any better way or json feature/annotation is available to achieve this ?

The reason I want this, In the Swagger Model Schema it is displaying all the fields available in EmplyeeDTO, I want to be specific here for a Create request A user should not see any of the the fields which are getting set in back end like id, createdBy etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using specific classes that represent clearly the data/behavior of the business use case is better (in terms of readability, maintainability) than mixing things that should not be.

> So a simple solutions can be I can create separate DTOs, like
>   EmployeeDTO, EmployeeCreateRequestDTO, EmployeeUpdateRequestDTO. But
>   it will leads to duplication of codes.

It will not create necessarily code duplication if all common fields to `EmployeeCreateRequestDTO` and `EmployeeUpdateRequestDTO` are present only in `EmployeeDTO`.

To avoid the duplication, you have two ways.

1) Inheritancy
`EmployeeCreateRequestDTO` and `EmployeeUpdateRequestDTO` are subclasses of `EmployeeDTO`.
Advantage : subclasses have a direct access to the public common getters/setters of the `EmployeeDTO` parent

2) Composition
Each one of these specific classes wraps a `EmployeeDTO` instance and define their own fields.
Advantage : subclasses have more flexibility to define which should be accessible from the `EmployeeDTO` field.